# How to insert an option value into a select tag with CasperJS?

Tags: select, phantomjs, casperjs

Well, the question is very self-explanatory.

Right now, I'm front of a form which has a select tag with a couple of options already. But I must insert a new one, with a different value that I will receive from a .json file.

The thing is: I haven't been able to find a suitable solution from the CasperJS documentation.

I've tried something like this:

```
this.fill('form.coworkerdiscountcode', {
'CoworkerDiscountCode.DiscountCode': ['Value1'] 
});
```

But no results. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any javascript code by passing it to `casper.evaluate` like this:

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("coworkerdiscountcode");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Kiwi";
    x.add(option);
});
```